# Change selected option using href action

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm currently working on a ftl page, and I need your help. I do have a list of users, that is displayed in a dropdown menu with no selected option. Beside this list there is an href "select current user", What I need to do is to change option to choose current user to be selected in the list. here is the code:

```
<select class="select" name="users" id="users">
        <#list users as user>
<option value="${user.id}">${user.firstName}</option>
    </#list>
</select>                       
     <a href="#">select current user</a>
```

BTW I do have currentUser.id.
Anyone know how to achieve this using JS & YUI? 
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
 <a href="#" 
 onclick="document.getElementById('users').value='$(currentUser.id}'; 
 return false">select current user</a>
```

which will work in newer browsers

Older (and newer) browser might want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectUser(val) {
  var users = document.forms[0].users;
  for (var i=0;i<users.length;i++) {
    if (users[i].text === val) {
      users[i].selected=true;
      break
    }
  }
  return false
}
</script>
<a href="#" id="${currentUser.id}"
 onclick="return selectUser(this.id)" >select current user</a>
```